# Null byte error, want to possibly remove null bytes without read, write, re-read in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am using python 3.

I am reading a CSV file into dictreader and am attempting to see which country has the most occurances.

Note that im using dictreader, and not reader. This is needed, i think, because i'm using Counter.

I am having trouble because some lines in my CSV file have null bytes (particularlly in the password field), and this kills my script with errors regarding csv reader not liking the null bytes. One example of this is on the last sample line in my comments below. I have seen that some people remove the null bytes with the line in my code: `readerobject(x.replace('\0', '') for x in csvfile)`  however I cannot seem to use this because i've already read the csvfile into the readerobject on the preceeding line.

Here is my code

```
'''
sample csv lines
Brazil,200.145.23.13,pi,raspberry,failed,None,None,None
Brazil,200.145.23.13,pi,raspberryraspberry993311,failed,None,None,None
China,121.201.83.134,root,123456,succeeded,None,None,None
United Kingdom,185.38.148.238,root,123456,succeeded,None,None,None
Croatia,5.188.10.141,root,admin,succeeded,None,None,None
France,195.154.44.31,squid,123456,failed,None,None,None
France,195.154.44.31,squid,123456,failed,None,None,None
Croatia,5.188.10.141,root,123456,succeeded,None,None,None
Croatia,5.188.10.141,root,admin,succeeded,None,None,None
Croatia,5.188.10.141,root,123456,succeeded,None,None,None
Netherlands,109.236.91.85,root,admin,succeeded,None,None,None
France,51.255.160.205,root,admin,succeeded,None,None,None
United States,207.138.132.44,root,seiko2005,failed,None,None,None
France,212.83.150.189,support,"       ",failed,None,None,None   <-- these are null bytes inside the ""  
'''


import codecs
from pprint import pprint  
from collections import Counter
import csv
linecount = 0
import time
country_counter = Counter()

print("parsing CSV log file")
with open('C:/Users/Home/Documents/kippo stuff/final lab/kippo/oldkippo4final.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    readerobject = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['Country', 'IP Address', 'Username', 'Password', 'Status', 'name', 'intention', 'OS'])
    readerobject(x.replace('\0', '') for x in csvfile)
    for row in readerobject:
        print(row, "\n\n")
        linecount +=1
        country_counter[row['Country']] +=1
        print(linecount)
print(country_counter.most_common(3))
print("the total linecount was: ", linecount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the whole file in, replace the 0x00 characters and then pass an `io.StringIO` object from that new string to `csv.DictReader`. This seems a bit hack'ish though. Maybe there's another function in the `csv` module that reads directly from strings instead of file objects?

```
import io

with open("oldkippo4final.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csvfile.read()   # read all

data = data.replace("\0", "")      # get rid of null-bytes
csvfile_repl = io.StringIO(data)   # new pseudo file object

readerobject = csv.DictReader(csvfile_repl, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['Country', 'IP Address', 'Username', 'Password', 'Status', 'name', 'intention', 'OS'])
```